# Drainage issues

Tags: outdoor

We live at the end of a cul de sac.  We are at the bottom of the hill.  During rainy season our property becomes saturated.  It seems to be causing erosion to our property.  Any suggestions who to contact or what to do?

Comment: Semi-seriously: Call a real estate agent and get it on the market during the dry season. Sounds like it's just plain poorly located. If you want mitigation options we'll need a lot more information, pictures, maps, diagrams to see what is happening and if or where things could be done about it.

Comment: @Ecnerwal Isn't that a little bit like taking your car with the faded hood out for a trade-in when it's raining?  Just saying...  ;-)

Comment: Having said that, Jill, is your property actually in a bowl, or just at the bottom of a hill? @Ecnerwal is right that more information is required to make any reasonable mitigation suggestions. There may be ways to create drainage to allow some excess water to flow off of your property, or divert it into existing storm drains or something.

Comment: @Craig No, it's like trading in your car that is possessed. Remember that the three most important things about real estate are location, location, location? That applies to BAD locations, too. The house at the bottom of the hill is going to get all the water from uphill no matter what you do - solving it may or may not be practical; moving out is one way to solve it. You can waste a lot of money and effort trying to solve insoluble problems that it would be simpler and more satisfying to move away from.

Comment: @Ecnerwal Okay, I actually laughed audibly. That's funny. I just meant, maybe it's fair to go ahead and disclose to the next buyer that there might be a poltergeist.  Of course, ultimately that's between you, your conscience and at least one other party if you're religious.

Comment: You can be liable for not disclosing known issues with a property upon sale. It is not just "caveat emptor", you have a duty to tell potential buyers about issues.

Comment: @JimmyFix-it Well, yeah, you, your conscience and at least two other parties if liability is determined. I don't know if bad drainage that makes your back yard a swamp is the same thing as not disclosing safety issues with the structure itself. But it's definitely a potential issue. For that matter, if it actually *is* a matter of actionable liability, there may be some recourse with regard to the original seller.

Comment: Landscape architect, drainage engineer

Comment: Lacking any more info on your particular situation for now, you might want to look at this Q&A and the links in them and the comments regarding swales and rain gardens. http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/67082/how-do-i-prevent-water-from-streaming-into-my-driveway/67084#67084

Answer (score 1):

Land drainage system around the back of the house to 'catch ' the water and carry it safely around the property.

We are in Norway and I've yet to see a flat plot lol! Most houses have some sort of trench with a perforated pipe in it and then backfilled with gravel. It's simple and it works.

Comment: Lots of groundwater in Norway (no doubt similar to Alaska)? I don't believe it!! </snark>  ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The quick solution would be to excavate a drainage channel or sluice on either side of your property so as to lead the water away  from your property. The drain trenches can be as simple as shoveling a continuous depression in the earth. Or as entailed as pouring a concrete channel. I'd also be concerned as to any adjoining properties down stream of you.

Comment: This is still presuming there is some kind of downhill slope to allow gravity to draw the water away, though. If the property sits in a depression, there just won't be anywhere for the water to go, unless you can tunnel some kind of culvert to connect a pipe to a downhill slope outside the depression.